# How to enclose a column with curly brackets and commas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

Could someone help me knowing how to enclose with curly brackets like this {years, data}, e.g. K7.

I want to do it for K8-K54, but I don't know what formula to use.

Comment: I kind of agree with bot.... no plainly obvious what you're after.  Looks like a custom number format?  Try `{@}`... right click the range, select _Format Cells_, select _Custom_ in the Category and enter the new format in the _Type_ box provided.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Substititute** to replace the space with a comma, and then **Concat** data together:

```
=CONCAT("{",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", ", "),"}")
```

[image]

Comment: What does "{",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", ", "),"} do?

Comment: Split the 1985 1.1623545 to1985,1.1623545